# animate images without using spritesheet in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

1.) I want to animate images in Cocos2d-x V2.2.3 without using spritesheet. 
I [image: Error is shown in the image Please help me]

2.) Or please provide me the url of tool which can make spritesheet free of cost. I have used texturepacker and its trial has expired now :(

Answer (score 0):

Spritesheets are really the way to go. TexturePacker is well worth the investment. Seriously.

If you dont want to use one, then your `addFrameWithFileName()` is incorrect now.

Just make normal `Sprite` out of each of those calls. There are other ways too.

Edit: Here is documentation: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Sprite_Sheet_Animation

Comment: can you please provide me code I tried to replace addFrameWithFileName() with Sprite but I failed :(